# Link 72 worksheets from 12 excel work books to MSACCESS

Tags: vba, excel

I have 12 months of monthly snap shot reports.
It turns out the expensive HR database wasn't set up to keep hold of historic data and just over writes a whole host of employee data with the most current.

I can rebuild and interrogate this record using the monthly snapshots, but there is SO MUCH to import into access and there has to be an automation.

I have 6 sheets named `Perm`, `Temps`, `Starters`, `PStarters`, `Leavers` and `TLeavers`.
I have 12 worksbooks named `12_OCT_16`, `11_SEP_16`, `10_AUG_16` etc, etc, etc. 
(There are actually 67 workbooks, but little steps)

I have got all of the Excel files into a folder. (`h:\reports\cleaned\`)

So I'm going to need to turn every sheet into its own table. (there are 10,000 employees so I just chuck it all into one table)

The tables need some kind of naming convention as they are imported.

So if I link `[Sheet Name]` from all .xlsm files in `[Directory]`
*can I get it to name the table it creates from the source sheet name and file name?*

If I can make that work then I can just change the sheet parameter 6 times I guess.

I only have MS OFFICE and a little i5 laptop.

Any help, advice, guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Some more detail is needed - Does the current range of A1 in all the sheets of all the workbooks encapsulate every record? are there any hidden rows in any sheets? and if so, do you want to exclude those records or unhide and move them over?

Comment: *So I'm going to need to turn every sheet into its own table*...no you don't. Databases are not spreadsheets. In fact, spreadsheets are usually queries from databases! You want to normalize data as much as possible, so **one** Employee table is the recommended structure.

Comment: Thanks for reading and responding.

Comment: Thanks for reading and responding.
Yes the A1 range captures everything. Nothing hidden or annoying.

I know data bases are not spread sheets. One table does not work as each employee has 25 parameters that could change monthly and the main staff sheet has 10000 rows. I can't see a way to sensibly create a one table that can adapt to that limit without hitting the 2gb limit in access. Doesn't help that my company wont roll out 64 bit windows.

Answer (score 1):

In MS Access' [DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844793.aspx) method, just give the table name argument a non-existent database table name and the method should create such a table in database. If you specify an existing table, method will attempt to append to it following current structure:

```
newtblName = WorbookNameVar & WorksheetNameVar
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
      newtblName, WorkbookPathVar, True, WorbookSheetVar & "!"
```

But as mentioned in comments, consider using one table and provide some indicator for distinguishing differences such as workbook/worksheet name. First import one of the Excel files and then add a column (Table / Design View) for `SourceLocation` as short text data type. Then loop through all other Excel files:

```
' ACCESS METHOD
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
      ExcelImportTable, WorbookPathVar, True, WorbookSheetVar & "!"

' SQL ACTION QUERY
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE TABLE ExcelImportTable SET SourceLocation = '" _
                     & WorbookNameVar & WorksheetNameVar & "'"
```

Do note: this all assumes Excel data is in tabular format starting in row `A1` with column headers.

Comment: Ok, there are a lot of repeated field headings that cut across the 6 types of Staff. (Current, Contractors, Starters x2, leavers x2) One monster table with every Staff ID repeated. That is going to be about 130,000 records

Comment: Welcome to the world of databases. You've graduated from flatfiles. And 130k is nothing! Ideally, you normalize further with a distinct Staff table with unique identifier, *StaffID* which is auto-generated by Access (not any user) and this ID is linked to a one-to-many join with *WorkDays* or *Projects* or *Orders*, each carrying own primary index AND *StaffID* and carrying your dated info and other details.

Comment: WHen I was straight importing these files to tables Access bloats the file to 2gb and my little laptop starts to cry. 
Staff ID is a unique identifier already, a constant across all sheets. That is why I was approaching this with multiple tables rather than 1 mega table because the same IDs are added every month.

Comment: How wide are your sheets? 130k records should not reach Access' 2GB limit. Again, there's no reason to keep duplicate structured tables (with date names) in relational databases. As long as the repeated StaffID has date indicators to distinguish, one should do. Also, one table vs many will not resolve the file size issue. Try multiple dbs by year -2014/2015/2016. In fact one is more efficient in storage (less structures/metadata).

Comment: sheets are about 40 wide. Nothing longer that 256 characters. There is A LOT of similar data types. After more thought I could probably get all sheets in to one table. Create an extra field for the sheet type and date.So  now I need to change this VBA to import all content to one table by matching field headings.